# How to show a static page with content, not blog posts, on an Octopress website?

Tags: octopress, portfolio

I am in the process of building an small portfolio website using Octopress. I chose this solution since I see more and more developers opting for it as a support for their technical blogs.

Aside from blog posts, there is an option to create pages which are apart from the posts history.
As I am still learning the platform, and would like to get this website up and running fast, which setting or template should I change to have a distinct page as the main one, instead of the blog itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source/index.html` is the entry page for your octopress blog.